# How to do arithmetic operations in expression?

Tags: sql, jpa, select, hql

We are tying to write a hql query. It is not recognizing + operator in SELECT clause.

```
X WHERE LL2 >=(SELECT XX+56 FROM SSK WHERE B='L')
```

I want to add XX with 56. Is it possible?

It is giving an error saying that XX 56 doesnt make sense. Specifically it is not recognizing + in between them.

Comment: That's possible but your HQL query is no valid. You have no aliases defined and Is SSK an entity?

Comment: Aliases is not required. SSK is a table name. I am just writing a  sample query without using real names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add 56 to select query.

Just use minus 56 from LL2. If you are passing LL2 value to the query you can do it before passing it.

```
 WHERE (LL2-56) >=(SELECT XX FROM SSK WHERE B='L')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try masking. The following works on mysql 5.5.32

```
SELECT `id`+23 FROM testtable;
```